# How can I add a patch to a distribution?

Tags: 9, composer, distributions

Distributions add patches as links to [www.drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org) / git.drupalcode.org, as these distributions.

- https://git.drupalcode.org/project/thunder/-/blob/6.3.x/composer.json
- https://git.drupalcode.org/project/lightning/-/blob/8.x-3.x/composer.json
- https://git.drupalcode.org/project/social/-/blob/11.2.x/composer.json

But it is not correct, because drupal.org/drupalcode.org is no patch hosting. And there are also patches dynamically generated from merge requests, which can be changed.

In our custom distribution, we added the patches in the repository (in the folder patches). But the only way, which worked, was to use the whole path to the site folder, like:

```json
"patches": {
  "drupal/core": {
    "#123456 Some patch": "web/profiles/custom/my-distro/patches/core/some.patch",
```

It works for our sites because all the sites have the same file structure, but it is not a good solution.

What is the correct solution?